# Wordpress add filter to the_content()

Tags: php, wordpress, function, filter

I'm trying to add a code to `the_content()` function. I tried the following

```
function add_something($content) {
    echo "test";
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_something', 6);
```

After adding the filter my posts return just the echo `test` without the content. How can I execute my custom code without omitting the content?

Comment: Is that your real function declaration? (See the `$` before the name). Also why don't you do something with the `$content` variable? Just because your function is called `add_` probably won't tell WP know that it wants to append something. (Actually it doesn't even do that. It just outputs before, I'd guess.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would surmise you need something like that (if it's indeed a filter callback):

```
function add_something($content) {
    return "test" . $content;
}
```

Seems what the docs say:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/add-something-to-the_content

Answer (score 8):

you omitted the return statement.

```
function add_something($content) {
echo "test";
... change $content ......
return $content;

}
```

Be advised that if you want to modify the content, you must append it to the variable. Using echo will output 'test' at the time the script is called. It will not append or prepend it to the_content()

Comment: Thank you! Do you mean like so.. `$content .= "test";
    return $content;`

Answer (score 0):

Use this (the_content filter needs 1 parameter)

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_something', 1);
```